# Vue3 Dockerize - vite: not found

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I try to dockerize my Vue3 project. Dockerfile is fine and work perfectly. But for development, I'm using a compose and when I up it, I got vie not found error.

This is Dockerfile

```
# develop stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN yarn build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this is compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  vue-app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: 'develop-stage'
    ports:
    - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
    - '.:/app'
    command: yarn dev
```

but I got this error:

```
/bin/sh: vite: not found
```

Comment: Can you run `yarn dev` on your host system, without involving Docker at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't copied any files between the `develop-stage` and `build-stage` so there's no `node_modules` and thus, no `vite`.

I recommend you create two separate Dockerfiles for development and production.

For example

#### Development

```bash
# Dockerfile.dev

FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
CMD yarn dev
```

```yaml
# compose.yaml

services:
  vue-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

#### Production

```bash
# Dockerfile

# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .
RUN yarn build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Thanks, It works well, But I can't open the app in my local browser. I changes ports to "5173:5173" but no effect.